# Is it possible to request a new secret key for Facebook API programmatically?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, credentials, secret-key

Is there a way to request a new secret key for Facebook via the facebook API? Essentially I would be using my own secret key to request a NEW secret key, for key rotation purposes.

I looked through the Facebook API documentation but could not find anything about this operation. I suspect they won't support it, but I would just like to confirm that there isn't an automatable way to rotate your API keys? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean "Access Token" when you say "Key", and you are talking about "User Access Tokens"? That´s not possible, you can only get a new User Token on user interaction. More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Not sure what you mean with key rotation, but the User Token is the only "Key" that can´t be valid forever, so i guess that´s what you are talking about...

Edit: Seems that you are indeed talking about the "App Secret", which can not be changed with the API but you can change it in your App settings. A rotation only makes sense if someone got your App Secret by accident or if some security issue happened. Better read this and only allow API calls server side: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer. I guess even though the api secret key can be valid forever, I wanted to rotate it because i sent some code to friends containing the hard-coded api secret key. I know I can request a new API secret from the facebook developer console, but I was just wondering whether there is a programmatic way to do it. I read it's good to switch your api secrets every so often for security purposes, e.g., if you have multiple people working on your project who then leave but still have access to API via the key.

Comment: never send the app secret to anyone...if you do that by accident, refresh it in the app settings immediately. and no, there is no programmatic way to change the app secret.

Comment: if people really leave a project, then it may be useful to change the app secret. but a general rotation once in a while is not neccessary.

Comment: i added some more information about securing api calls

Comment: Cool, this is great. Thank you!